Facebook shows my email address without dots?
I went to Facebook Marketplace and when I am trying to "Email seller" (pushed that blue button), the following form appears:

The problem is that when I click on "your email address", it will show my email address without a dot between my names, and doesn't allow me to change it! Why is that??

It you have a @gmail.com or @googlemail.com email address, it will work fine without the dots. Some other email providers also do the same, but not all.

@doubleunary Thanks, but why does the stupid Facebook modify my email address? Doesn't make any sense.

Chances are that you will not get an answer to that here, unless there is a Facebook spokesperson that comes across this thread. Contact Facebook to ask them, or simply look in their help center.
